# Не могу перезапустить spider (scrapy) для регулярного парсинга веб-сайта

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

Мой код:

```
def start_parce():
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

    process.crawl(SpiderCardSpider)
    settings = process.settings
    settings.set("FEEDS", {
    "items.json": {"format": "json"},
})
    process.settings = settings
    process.start()
    process.stop()

def start_parce_time():
    while True:
        start_parce()
        time.sleep(60)
        os.remove('results.json')
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
2023-11-24 18:24:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-11-24 18:24:03 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-11-24 18:24:03 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "D:\fa-treid\card_parc\card_parc\spiders\spider_card.py", line 59, in <module>
    start_parce_time()
  
File "D:\fa-treid\card_parc\card_parc\spiders\spider_card.py", line 52, in start_parce_time
    start_parce()
  
File "D:\fa-treid\card_parc\card_parc\spiders\spider_card.py", line 44, in start_parce
    process.start()
  
File "D:\fa-treid\venv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 427, in start
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)  # blocking call
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
File "D:\fa-treid\venv\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", line 254, in run
    self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
  
File "D:\fa-treid\venv\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1299, in startRunning
    ReactorBase.startRunning(cast(ReactorBase, self))
  
File "D:\fa-treid\venv\Lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 843, in startRunning
    raise error.ReactorNotRestartable()
twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему вызовом команды из терминала:

```
def run_script_per():
    command = 'cd .. && cd .. && cd card_parc && scrapy crawl spider_card -O 
    results.json'
    subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

Правда я не думаю, что это хорошее решение.